# Order status randomly changes upon invoicing and shipping

Tags: order-status

Every order on my Magento store seems to be going through multiple order statuses unnecessarily before reaching it's correct status. Attached below is an example (I have numbered them for easier communication):

[image: Complete order cycle from creation to shipping]

Let me explain what's happening here:

1. Customer clicks "Place order" button.
2. Magento saves the order and redirects to the payment gateway.

At this point, the order says "Pending" and I know that the customer has no yet completed the payment yet. At this point, the Order State is "New".

3. Payment gateway returns a successful payment. Status changes to "Payment Done" which I have set as a default status for order state "Processing".
4. Internal use, this is where we extract the order using CSV and change it to "In Production"

5 to 8. This is where things get absurd. At this point I am initiating a bulk "Create Invoice" action. Notice how it goes through all those status within 38 seconds and comes back to "Preparing Order". Note: The order state is still "Processing".

9 & 10. I again run the bulk "Ship Orders" action and this thing ends up correctly at "Shipped" with order state as "Complete" but why is it doing that twice?

Did I set up the whole state / status thing wrong? Is it the bulk action that's screwing up? What is the right way of doing this?

Attaching the screenshot of my Order Status screen as well:
[image: Ignore the ones not in use]

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Jugal